# peewee: object has no attribute _meta

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, peewee

I am working on Windows with Python 3.3 32-bit. I have installed peewee and want to try some of its features. I have started with Peewee Quickstart (http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html).

My code looks like this:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    is_relative = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
            database = db

class Pet(Model):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Person, related_name = "pets")
    name = CharField()
    animal_type = CharField()

    class Meta:
            database = db

Person.create_table()
Pet.create_table()
```

and I get an error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2094, in create_table
db = cls._meta.database
AttributeError: type object 'Person' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Is something wrong with my installation of peewee? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peewee is *not* Python 3 compatible; it only works with Python 2 at the moment.

The error you see is a result of that; the `Model` class defines a metaclass using Python 2 techniques, which have changed for Python 3.

**Update**: [Version 2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/peewee/2.1.0), released 2013-04-02, adds Python 3 compatibility. The package now supports Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.2 and up.